# How to check pre-version for kubeadm cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

For some reason, I can not easily get the k8s.gcr.io containers in my server. The workaround is to fetch containers locally and then move it to my server. My question is how to pre-get all messages of version for all kubeadm cluster containers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print a list of images `kubeadm` will use, you can run the following command:

```
$ kubeadm config images list
```

As an example you can see the images that will be used for my `kubeadm` `v1.20`:

```
$ kubeadm config images list
k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver:v1.20.5
k8s.gcr.io/kube-controller-manager:v1.20.5
k8s.gcr.io/kube-scheduler:v1.20.5
k8s.gcr.io/kube-proxy:v1.20.5
k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.2
k8s.gcr.io/etcd:3.4.13-0
k8s.gcr.io/coredns:1.7.0
```